# contact form 7 de wordpress no adjunta archivos

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, contact-form-7

Estoy haciendo una página con `wordpress` y me he encontrado un un inconveniente a la hora de enviar mails con archivos adjuntos usando el plugin contact form 7. 
Cuando lleno el formulario, incluyendo el archivo adjunto y presiono enviar me sale este mensaje:

> "Se ha producido un error subiendo la imagen"

¿Alguien sabe que podría estar mal? les dejaré capturas de pantalla y la estructura del formulario.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="container" style="background: #248211;"><p style="color:#fff; padding:10px;">Datos personales</p></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

<label> Nombres: (requerido)
    [text* your-name] </label>

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

<label> Apellidos: (requerido)
[text* apellidos]</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 form-control">
<label> Sexo: (requerido)</label>
[radio sexo use_label_element default:1 "Masculino" "Femenino"]
</div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<label> Fecha de nacimiento: (requerido)
[date* date min:1945-01-01 max:2018-01-01]</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<label>Nacionalidad: (requerido) 
[text* nacionalidad]</label>
</div>


</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<label>Tipo de documento: (requerido)
[select tipo_doc include_blank "DNI" "CI" "LE"]</label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<label>Número de documento: (requerido)
[text* num_doc]</label>
</div>

</div>

<label> Tu correo electrónico (requerido)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<div class="container" style="background: #248211;"><p style="color:#fff; padding:10px;">Estudios realizados</p></div>

<label>Rama de estudio: (requerido)
[text* rama]</label>

<div class="container" style="background: #248211;"><p style="color:#fff; padding:10px;">Experiencia laboral</p></div>


<label> Experiencia laboral: (requerido)
[textarea* experiencia]</label>

<div class="container" style="background: #248211;"><p style="color:#fff; padding:10px;">Archivos adjuntos</p></div>


<label>Aduntar CV: (requerido)</label>

[file* cv limit:2mb filetypes:pdf|doc|docx|odt]


    <div class="pull-right">
    [submit "Enviar"]
    </div>

    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fíjate si existe en el servidor la carpeta `wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads` ahi se guardan temporalmente los adjuntos

Answer (score 0):

1- Es probable que **no tengas permisos de escrituras** para almacenar el archivo de manera temporal. Comprueba los permisos de carpeta e intenta ponerlos a **775 o 777**

2- La ubicación de la carpeta temporal es *wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads* de forma predeterminada. Puede variar si ha cambiado la configuración de la ruta de carga desde *wp-content/uploads*. En ambas, revisa sus permisos.

3- Fijate bien que tipo de archivo estas intenta do enviar por correo.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda, mas info visita: https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Answer (score 0):

otra opción es que estés excediendo el tamaño máximo permitido.

por ejemplo puedes configurar tu php.ini con estos valores:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 20M
```

Comment: Hola, logré solucionarlo. Tuve que generar un archivo php.ini para el directorio dónde tengo alojada la web y además cambiar la ruta de los archivos temporales de wordpress